# Postgresql + The connection attempt failed

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I use JPA and EclipseLink to communicate with postgresql. My queries does not work occasionally.The following error is issued:

> [EL Info]: 2017-11-28
>   19:23:52.408--UnitOfWork(533346156)--Communication failure detected
>   when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction.
>   Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt
>   failed.

Comment: Can you show your persistence.xml? And it would help if you could point the piece of code where it does not work.

Comment: Not familiar with EclipseLink, I use Hibernate, but change persistence.xml to output the SQL. Also you should also examine the postgresql log on the machine that hosts the database.

Comment: @M. Jamshidi you might not want to post your ip address/password/username

Comment: This error is also issued:  [EL Info]: 2017-11-28 19:23:04.126--ServerSession(836371508)--Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Error Code: 0

Comment: Call: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM active_fault WHERE ((object_name = ?) AND (end_time IS NULL))
 bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=ActiveFault sql="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM active_fault WHERE ((object_name = ?) AND (end_time IS NULL))").

Comment: Do you have a firewall or something in between which might kill long lived connections? How are you setting up data source to your db?